# How do I find the dependencies when building software from source?

Tags: compiling

Here is what I have done.
I downloaded foxtrotgps.1.1.1.tar.gz as it is the latest to /home/crash/usr/local.src
I extracted it to my /home/crash/usr/local/src as directory /foxtrotgps.1.1.1

I then checked all the required packages for the correct level, and they were or if missing, I added them.

So I then go to the FTGPS directory and do ./configure, and it gets to where it says;

```
No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
No package 'gdk-2.0' found
No package 'gthread-2.0' found
```

But the gtk+-2.0 is there, but I don't find gdk or gthread. And it stops and goes nowhere. What am I doing wrong - what package dependencies am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

#### the proviso

I'm assuming that you are using a recent version of ubuntu such as 12.04.  The versions in the repository are considered *stable* - so perhaps you may wish to use that version.

However if you like living on the cutting-edge - compiling or installing from a PPA is the way-to go.  Just remember, this route can leave your system in a potential unstable state.

#### how to compile

The dependencies you need to install this are as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install autotools-dev intltool libbluetooth-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexif-dev libgconf2-dev libglade2-dev libgps-dev libgtk2.0-dev  libsoup2.4-dev  libsqlite3-dev libxml2-dev
```

Remember also to install the package `build-essential` i.e.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

#### so how did I know that

... well I sort of cheated.

Search on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com) for your package - I looked for `foxtrotgps` in the Quantal repository.

[image]

Look at the resources and look for the debian.tar.xz file.  Click on it - it will open in the archive manager.  Navigate to the `control` file in the debian folder.

[image]

In the build-depends section are the packages Launchpad needs to build the source - its the same packages you need to install.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you can compile a new version without using the PPAs for the source dependencies, and use the great `build-dep` feature in Ubuntu. Make sure you have the source packages selected and have this line in your sources.list file:

```
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
```

You can check by entering in the terminal `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

I have successfully compiled `Stellarium 0.11.3`, `Scummvm 1.5.0`, and others by obtaining the dependencies with `build-dep`; for example:

`sudo apt-get build-dep scummvm`

For packages already in the repositories, you can check dependencies with:

`apt-cache show foxtrotgps`

and **compare** that with the dependencies required for the newer version, which will be listed on the program's website, or in a readme with the source code download.

Usually when obtaining the dependencies via the `build-dep` method you must then download the **stable source code** from the site of the program, and not the development or git version. It will **not** always be possible to compile a new version in this way, but it is worth trying. (Gimp 2.8, for example, requires a later version of Gtk and that can't be met by using the source files for Precise.)

However, I have used the `build-dep` method successfully for **Foxtrotgps**; simply follow these steps (assuming you have installed `build-essential`):

- Download the most recent stable source code (version 1.1.1 at the moment) from [the Foxtrot site](http://www.foxtrotgps.org/releases/foxtrotgps-1.1.1.tar.gz)
- Open the terminal and enter `sudo apt-get build-dep foxtrotgps`
- Uncompress the downloaded source code with `tar xzvf <file>` and `cd` to the foxtrot folder. Then run the following three commands:
- `./configure`
- `make`
- `sudo checkinstall` (install `checkinstall` if you don't have it, or use `sudo make install`)

Below is a screenshot of the compiled program, foxtrotgps:

[image: foxtrot]