# How do I find the build dependencies of aircrack-ng?

Tags: compiling, make

I have been trying for a day now to install a package thats given as source code and everything i have tried gives me errors and i would like to know if theres a way to look in the files or something other than looking on the Internet or site of the program for dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aircrack ng page [has the instructions](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_aircrack):

> Kernel headers and gcc as well as make have to be installed on your
>   system. On Debian-based distros (Debian, Ubuntu, Xubuntu, …), issue
>   the following command in a console to install them: `sudo apt-get
>   install build-essential`
>
> #### OpenSSL (development).
>
> It is called
>   openssl-dev or libssl-dev depending on your distribution.

On ubuntu it's libssl-dev, so the full command to install the build dependencies is:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev
```

See also:

- [How do I find the dependencies when building software from source?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172367/how-do-i-find-the-dependencies-when-building-software-from-source)