# configure flags

Tags: package-management, compiling

What is the Ubuntu way of downloading the source for a package and then building it while passing specific flags to the configure portion of the process? I hope I'm explaining what I mean properly.

Installing from source follows almost always the following procedure:

```
./configure --FLAG-1 --FLAG-2
make && make install
```

How can I get control over specifying flags1 and 2 in the configure process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download the source for most packages in the Ubuntu Repos. To compile a package from source, you would do something like this:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep doodad
```

This will install any dependencies. Now download the source code:

```
apt-get source doodad
cd doodad*
```

Edit `debian/rules` to customize the build process:

```
$EDITOR debian/rules
```

Finally, build it as a `.deb` (for easy uninstalling/dependency resolution):

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b
```

(the arguments will tell the command to fake root, to not sign the package, and to not include the source)

Now you can install the package you just built with this command:

```
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i doodad-<version>-ubuntu-<crap>.deb
```

(make sure to install the non `-dev` version)

Then you can clean up with:

```
rm -rf doodad*
```

#### This was tested on Ubuntu 12.04, with the `irssi` package. Your results may vary.

Answer (score 0):

For a general explanation of how to build from source see my answer here:

- [How do I find the dependencies when building software from source?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172367/how-do-i-find-the-dependencies-when-building-software-from-source/172793#172793)

To address your *specific* question here about `./configure` please read on:

To gain a list of the appropriate flags and options available for the program you are compiling, enter

```
./configure --help
```

Part of a sample file for `Pinta` generated from the above command:

> `configure' configures pinta 1.3 to adapt to many kinds of systems.
>   Usage: ./configure [OPTION]... [VAR=VALUE]...
>   To assign environment variables (e.g., CC, CFLAGS...), specify them as
>   VAR=VALUE.
>
> Some influential environment variables:
>
> PKG_CONFIG  path to pkg-config utility
>     PKG_CONFIG_PATH  directories to add to pkg-config's search path
>     PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR  path overriding pkg-config's built-in search path
>     CC          C compiler command
>     CFLAGS      C compiler flags
>     LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L< lib dir > if you have libraries in a
>                 nonstandard directory
>     LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l
>     CPPFLAGS    (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I< include dir > if
>                 you have headers in a nonstandard directory
>     CPP         C preprocessor

You can override the default options by specifying locations of packages or libraries if they are in non-standard locations or have different names than `configure` expects as [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501259/how-to-get-a-configure-script-to-look-for-a-library?rq=1) showed. For more on flags as used in the configure script itself, see [this discussion here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404746/best-practices-for-cflags-handling-in-configure-scripts?rq=1)

Or if the program is not to be installed in the default location (the `/usr/local` hierarchy) you can specify, for example

```
./configure --prefix=/my/custom/location
```

There are many more options that can be used, and the list of commands passed to `./configure` can become very long, but it is all very specific to the program you are compiling; very often no special options are needed.